# How can I overcome AMP Story for Wordpress Error?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

After a bit of use on the AMP Wordpress Native (Google) App, the "AMP Story" feature dies on me. My hosting company saw nothing on their end. Said perhaps PHP resource issue and ask the developer but he was only guessing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpFmI.png)